# Javascript onload MVC ASP .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to stop this piece of code from running when the webpage loads.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-md-pull-4" value="Download" id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction">

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mybutton") = @api.function();
}
</script>
```

Whenever I load the page, this connects to the web api and launches the api.function code. I only want this to happen when the button I have is clicked.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I don't think you are including all your code because that function would only get called when you click the button based on what you posted. If you want to know what is calling it then look at the stack trace at execution. To do this add a new line in the function and write `debugger;`, then load the page in the browser of choice with the Developer/Debug tools open which should stop script execution at that point. Then look at the stack trace and figure out what is making the call.

Comment: Also I/we have no idea what `@api.function()` does, are you sure the call to the api is not being made from the server and not the client?

Comment: The issue is that your server side code `@api.function()` is called when the server-side code runs.

Look at the source in the browser (open page, view source) - you'll see that the result of `@api.function()` is embedded in the source.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do as you can't assign to `document.getElementById("mybutton")` (trying to set the html? the caption? start a download?) but you're not getting that far (nor as far as the missing `()` on the onclick).

Within the onclick, you should make an ajax call to your server side api function - there's plenty of answers on SO on how to do this, but without more info as to what you're trying to do / what the api returns.

Comment: Your original question had more specific code and was easier to write an answer on. You should post that code in your question.

Comment: The api.function simply executes a process in an external application. It shouldn't be relevant to why it's executing on page load. It must be making the call from the client. 
I want to click the button and have api.function execute and make the call to the api and perform the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> Paul: It (`@api.function()`) executes a workflow in an external program. Essentially just starts a process in a different application. Is there anyway to stop Razor rendering it on page load and only when I click the button?

Short answer - No. You are confusing server side and client side code. There is a distinction. The server side code is executed in the Model, in the Controller, and in the razor View. The client side code is executed using JavaScript in the context of the web browser but this code has no access to the server side code/processes. The only access it has is the same access as anything running from a browser, it uses HTTP calls to the server using URLs and passed in data.

If you want `@api.function()` to be called on click you have these options:

1. Post back - create a post back / submit and start this process from your MVC Controller. In this case remove the client script tag completely and rely on server code to start the process.
2. Create new public method in either your existing MVC controller OR a new Web API controller. Mark this method with `HttpPost` attribute and then call it using a [JQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call. This will allow the call to be submitted without the need for a form post.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks @Igor

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to call a server method onload? can't you just load in the data that you need from start?

in any case an alternative with jquery:

```
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){
   // call server
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Razor renders @api.function() and the result of the rendering is the execution of the function. Can you explain what is @api.function() and what does it do?

Comment: It executes a workflow in an external program. Essentially just starts a process in a different application. Is there anyway to stop Razor rendering it on page load and only when I click the button?

Comment: @Paul - no. You are getting client side code confused with server side code. You cant mix the 2.

Comment: Ok so maybe this will explain better:
On page load, I initalise a connection to the application.
I want the page to load the html on the page. 
On the page is a button. When I click this button, I want the webservice to perform a function. 
Code:
 Webservice client = new Webservice();
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-md-pull-4" id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myButton") =  @client.executeObject();
  }
 </script>